# Optimistic lock in Doctrine2 doesn't work for many to many relation

Tags: php, concurrency, doctrine-orm, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I have entity `User` which has many to many relation to roles. I've tried to implement Optimistic lock, everything works fine, just when I changed roles, it doesn't change the version (User entity version), is this proper behaviour?

```
class User {
    /**
     * User's roles.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     */
     private $roles;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine 2's locking mechanisms don't take associations into account. They only protect against changes to the entities themselves. IMHO this is expected, because it has no way to know which associations to include and which to ignore. This isn't something you'd want to happen blindly on all associations.

Theoretically Doctrine 2 could achieve this by adding an option to the association mappings, but at this moment that simply isn't supported.

So you have 2 options:

1. Try to implement such a feature, and submit a PR :)
2. Implement your own optimistic locking mechanism that does take this specific association into account.

Comment: I have been worried about this case, are you sure about this, right?

Comment: Yes I'm sure :) Have a look at the code (especially the persisters and hydrators).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but I think this is proper bahaviour (because flush don't modify User entity) and there is no reason to lock User entity - it's not changed.

Comment: I think there is a reason to lock, because entity is being changed, relation is a part of the entity, isn't it? So if you changed your roles in user, you expect that is locking this entity as well. Because someone else can change roles as well and it will be inconsistent.

Comment: You didn't write about locking "Role" entity anything, and the problem is in locking Role not a user (based on your reply).
And what about situation when two users has the same role? Application should change version of two users? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: No I didn't because I am not talking about locking Role entity, but User entity. I don't update Role entity, but ManyToMany connection on User entity.

with
"Because someone else can change roles as well and it will be inconsistent"
I mean change ManyToMany relation in User, so user have for example roles admin and tester. With change I mean someone add new role to user, or remove old one.

Comment: "just when I changed roles, it doesn't change the version"

Comment: Ok, I get it. Why you can't change updatedAt in roles setter? It will update version. It's a workaround - I know;)

Comment: I meant roles in User entity, as previous comment described.

Comment: Mmm I will try this one, I didn't know about updateAt attribute. Thanks.

Comment: You shuld have field updatedAt. It's very important to timestamp entities. You can use Gedmo Doctrine Extension. It provides tools to automatically update on create/update, soft delete and other features :)

If your application is Symfony2 based, it's a bundle for this. https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Comment: I see, not really I have version without timestamp, doctrine documentation recommends this type of version. I will try then update version number, but it's not really nice solution though.

Comment: Doctrine should it change directly in SQL, don't modify it!
You should have updatedAt and createdAt fields, just FYI (and maybe it be usefull in future).

Comment: Yes I think so, so we are again on the beginning :) Why it doesn't change version, when you change ManytoMany relation...

Comment: Where you have owning side of relation (where is specified JoinTable)?

Comment: Just in User entity  /**
     * User's roles.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     */
    private $roles;

Comment: So that's the problem. Doctrine listens on changes only on owning side of relation. Based on your comment, in role you have @orm\manytomany and @orm\joinTable - here is owning side). I think, if you try save Role (with added one new user) version of that role will be changed. But, if it doesn't work, you should implement timestamps fields and update it during adding new role to user entity.

Comment: Not at all, as I wrote in previous comment User entity is owning side.

Comment: So post full annotation in User entity not a part :)
Ok, If owning side is in right place try with timestamps. I don't have any other idea how to deal with it.